# Installed new Leviton DW15S light Switch. light turns on, but does not turn off

Tags: electrical, switch, light

i installed a new Leviton DW15S light switch.  the lights turn on, but they do not turn off at all. whether i push the switch button to On or Off, the lights stay ON.
i must have connected the wires wrongly.  i am including few pictures.  can someone please offer helpful advice? thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you accidentally reverse the "line" black and "load" black?

Comment: Please untangle the mess of wires in the box then take a new pic so we can see what's attached to what. Also, this is a smart switch, so in what way is it not turning off? By the physical switch, through the app, automatically? Much more detail is needed.

Comment: it is not turning off by the physical switch buttons.  i change the Switch with a new one, but same problem.  i doubt the switch is damaged/broken.  it must be my wiring.

Comment: What type of switch was there before? I am wondering if that white is a neutral or a hot from a switch leg , more information is needed swap the 2 blacks if the white really is a neutral having the line and load reversed can cause some electronic switches (scr) to latch

Answer (score 4):

Websearch suggests the Leviton DW15S is a smart switch. If so, then yes, it may matter which black is line (unswitched power in) and which is load (switched power out). Some newer smart switches will work either way, some don't, and I'm not sure about this model without checking its installation instructions.

If that *is* the cause, exchanging the two black wires would solve it. But it would be better to actually know which wire was which rather than guessing. Even a cheap non contact voltage probe could probably answer that for you.